# Numpy n-d array multiplication

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I have tried multiplying `a=np.array([1,2,3])` and `b=np array([[1]])` and I am getting `[[1,2,3]]`....can you tell me how are they reaching to this result?

What I was expecting is `[[1],[2],[3]]`

I would be grateful if someone can answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another dimension with [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get expected result:

```
>>> a * b
array([[1, 2, 3]])

>>> a[:, None] * b
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> a.shape
(3,)

>>> a[:, None].shape
(3, 1)
```

You can also use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> np.einsum('i,jk->ik', a, b)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please improve your question by using the formatting tools stackoverflow provide.

In this case it's simple to read your question, so I will answer to it: you are using the `*` operator for multiplication instead of the `np.dot()` or `np.matmul()` functions. The `*` operator performs element-wise multiplication, which may not give you the result you're expecting in this context.

Try run

```
a = a.reshape(3,1)
result = np.dot(a, b)
```

and see if the result matches your expectation.

Actually after performing the reshape using `a = a.reshape(3,1)` both `np.dot(a, b)` and `a * b` gives you the same result, but this happens only in your specific example! If you need to do the dot product then use `np.dot()`!